# Create Feature and store to different FGDB

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

Create Feature and store to different FGDB
I'm creating a feature and I want to store it to a specific geodatabase. At the moment I'm using feature.Store() but it's not storing it to where I want. How do I specify a location?

I want to store it to C:\College Stuff\Dissertation\2009 stuff\Geo\Geo\Full_3D.gdb

I've been told that if I am looking to store in a particular database I will need to open the feature class from that database.

I've looked at connecting to a geodatabase using this code

```
    Public Shared Function FileGdbWorkspaceFromPath(ByVal FGDB_WORKSPACE As String) As IWorkspace
    Dim factoryType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory")
    Dim workspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType), IWorkspaceFactory)
    Return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(FGDB_WORKSPACE, 0)
End Function
```

This is my CreateFeature sub

```
 Public Sub CreateFeature(ByVal layername1 As String, ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double, ByVal FeatureClass1 As IFeatureClass)

    Dim cPoint As IPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
    ' To individually assign a value to the coordinates, use cPoint.X = x and cPoint.Y = y.
    cPoint.PutCoords(x, y)


    ' Ensure the feature class contains points.
    If FeatureClass1.ShapeType <> esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint Then
        Return
    End If

    ' Build the feature.
    Dim feature As IFeature = FeatureClass1.CreateFeature()
    feature.Shape = cPoint



    ' Commit the new feature to the geodatabase.
    feature.Store()

End Sub
```

To create the feature do I need to connect to the geodatabase in the CreateFeature sub? How do I do that? I'm modifying someone elses code and I am new to this so that's why I am very unsure

Here is the GetFeatureClass function, this where the CreateFeature gets the feature from. GetFeatureClass gets a feature class from the active map. The feature class is a single shapefile, I want it to get a feature class that is in the active map but in a geodatabase

```
Public Function GetFeatureClass(ByVal layername1 As String) As IFeatureClass
    Dim mxDocument As IMxDocument
    mxDocument = m_application.Document
    Dim map As IMap = mxDocument.FocusMap
    Dim check As Boolean = False

    Dim layerCounter As Integer
    Dim FeatureClass1 As IFeatureClass = Nothing
    Dim featureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Dim currentLayer As ILayer
    For layerCounter = 0 To map.LayerCount - 1 Step layerCounter + 1
        currentLayer = map.Layer(layerCounter)

        If (TypeOf currentLayer Is IFeatureLayer) And (currentLayer.Name = layername1) Then


            featureLayer = currentLayer

            FeatureClass1 = featureLayer.FeatureClass

            check = True

            layerCounter = map.LayerCount
        End If
    Next

    If check = False Then
        MsgBox("cannot find InputStops layer")
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return FeatureClass1
End Function
```

Comment: Looking at your code I would suspect that the FeatureClass you are bringing into function CreateFeature as a parameter is from the wrong geodatabase as this code looks OK to me. So you need to review the code that is getting a handle on that featureclass which is code you are not showing. Try dropping a messagebox displaying the alias name to confirm what you are passing in and then work back from that?

Comment: Sorry @Hornbydd yes I have a GetFeatureClass function that gets the feature class for the active map. At the moment the feature class is a single shapefile, however, my modification is that the feature class is in a feature dataset within a geodatabase. I added the GetFeatureClass function to my original post. How can I change this, or create a new one, that will get the feature class that I want within the dataset and geodatabase?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get hold of a FeatureClass directly is this method. The FeatureDataset is WBD and the FeatureClass is WBDLine.

```
Public Sub GetFeatureclass()
   Dim pGPUtil As IGPUtilities2
   Set pGPUtil = New GPUtilities
   Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass
   Set pFeatureClass = pGPUtil.OpenFeatureClassFromString("c:\scratch\nhdh_dc.gdb\WBD\WBDLine")
   Debug.Print pFeatureClass.FeatureCount(Nothing)
End Sub
```

There are other ways but if you know the full path then this is quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet. How do I call that in a main method? In 2my code, there is the main part where GetFeatureClass is called. It goes 'Dim FeatureClass1 As IFeatureClass = GetFeatureClass("layername)'. How would I replicate that with your method?

Comment: When calling GetFeatureClass() how do I get set it equal to a variable. I've tried Dim feature1 As IFeatureClass = GetfeatureClass() but it does not return a variable.

Comment: My code example is a very simple procedure to show you how to use gputilities. You want to convert it into a function or place the code directly into your code. If you do not know how to create a function then you need to read up on that subject as that is basic programming which you must understand first.